# New rails 3 app, what .js files can I delete? Want to use jQuery not prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

New rails 3 app, what .js files can I delete? Want to use jquery not prototype.

Actually I'm pretty sure I won't be using any of the built in ajax functionality, I like to go custom.

Answer (score 2):

All of them, though you may want to keep `application.js` as it's a blank file you can use to insert your own custom javascript. But the `prototype.js`, `effects.js`, etc. are all Prototype-specific.

If you do use jQuery, there's a specific jQuery `rails.js` file for the unobtrusive javascript stuff: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: What you should keep in mind is that the jquery-ujs has a rake task to install so it deletes the necessary files itself.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that you can skip Prototype when the app is created

```
Rails new app --skip-prototype
```